# Проблема с запуском flask приложения на Centos 7

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

**httpd.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:88>
ServerName <myserver.com>

WSGIDaemonProcess feedlerbot user=apache group=apache threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/feedler/feedler_bot/bot.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/feedler/feedler_bot/>
    WSGIProcessGroup feedlerbot
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**bot.wsgi:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

# activate virtualenv
activate_this = '/var/www/feedler/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

# path to flask app
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/feedler/feedler_bot')

from bot import app as application
```

**bot.py:**

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)


# Empty webserver index, return nothing, just http 200
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'HEAD'])
def index():
    return 'Feedler Bot using webhooks works fine!'


# Process webhook calls
@app.route(WebhooksSetting.WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)


"""Start of the bot logic"""
<bot_logic>
"""End of the bot logic"""

# Remove webhook, it fails sometimes the set if there is a previous webhook
bot.remove_webhook()

time.sleep(1)

# Set webhook
bot.set_webhook(url=WebhooksSetting.WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WebhooksSetting.WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,
                certificate=open(WebhooksSetting.WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))

# Start flask server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=WebhooksSetting.WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
            port=WebhooksSetting.WEBHOOK_PORT,
            ssl_context=(WebhooksSetting.WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, WebhooksSetting.WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV),
            debug=True)
```

Порт 88 открыт, но при попытке открыть в браузере https://myserver.com:88/ - connection refused. В логах /etc/httpd/logs/error_log пусто. Где я мог ошибиться? Причем на этом же сервере запущен и корректно работает телеграм бот ровно по такой же схеме, но только на порту 8443.

Comment: Вроде как у апача есть ещё некий ports.conf, в котором тоже должен быть прописан пор 88

Comment: У Вас Apache запущен с правами root? А то ведь порт 88 - привилегированный. Также советую проверить iptables

Comment: Телнетом можно достучаться до порта.

Comment: Если достучаться до порта можно, то ошибки connection refused быть не может, потому что эта ошибка означает, что достучаться до порта таки нельзя. Значит где-то что-то вы не договариваете